# How to add external jar to GWT project?

Tags: gwt

My GWT project in Eclipse contains server code which requires to connect to a database and process data. For this to work, an external jar file should be added.

I added it via Project->Properties->BuildPath->Lib->add external jar...

The jar file is seen in Referenced libraries in the package explorer in, but the development mode still shows a class not found exception. What might cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To use the jar on the server side, it should be copied into your `/war/WEB-INF/lib` directory as well as added to your build path in eclipse.

To add the jar to the gwt client side, it must have a gwt module xml definition, and you must add the module to your project's module (it's `gwt.xml` file).

Comment: For more detailed instructions on 3rd party libraries check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515459/adding-external-jar-in-gwt