# Adding external jar in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a jar file with source code packed.

i inserted the jar in war/WEB-INF/lib/xxx.jar Add to build path

but when i run the project i got an error

**Edited Added gwt.xml**

```
  <module rename-to='bookmanagementsystem'>

  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
  <inherits name='com.example.Book'></inherits>
  <entry-point class='com.example.Book.client.Index'/>  
  
</module>
```

**Edited**

I solved
**Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997**

Now i got a problem

```
Loading inherited module 'com.example.book'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/example/book.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
      [ERROR] Line 6: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
```

Comment: can you please post the .gwt.xml file code also?

Comment: Is it sure that you have Book.gwt.xml file in com.example? Please tell the package of jar file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to include external jar to GWT then make sure you did the following

1. check the jar has .gwt.xml file and it must specify the source.
2. add it to lib folder
3. configure build path and add jar to libraries
4. select the jar from Order and Export
5. inherits this module in your .gwt.xml file

Eg. if you have a package in  jar named "sample.source" and your .gwt.xml file in jar is "Source.gwt.xml" and this .gwt.xml file in "sample" folder and classes or entities in "source" folder

Then your current project must inherits it. ie it must have the following tag

```
 <inherits name='sample.Source'/>
```

Eg :
Sorce.gwt.xml in jar file

```
<module>
 <source path="">
 <include name="**/MyEntity.java"/>
 </source>
</module>
```

For reference :http://jonathan.lalou.free.fr/?p=1077

GWT is not supporting serialization in client side so try to use RPC  and use these classes from jar in server or you just copy the packages of jar and add to src of gwt project.

OR

**I solved the problem the jar files must have java source code along with class files or pack java source code into jar and use.**

Comment: check this :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251782/how-to-inherit-a-required-module-in-to-gwt-project

Comment: @Parvathy i tried jar having java source code along with class file still have the same problem

Comment: @Parvathy now i have got an error "No source code is available for type com.example.module.model.Person; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.yal.BMS.client.Index'"

Comment: @Bucks did you inherit this(com.example.module.model.Person) module in .gwt.xml file? I mean there is a .gwt.xml file in this package you have to inherit it in your current projects's gwt.xml

Comment: I mean if this module is not a gwt project then create Module.gwt.xml file in com.example, it must have the following content<module>
 <source path="module">

 </source>
</module>

Comment: @Bucks inherits .gwt.xml file only.  <inherits name='com.example.module.model> .

Comment: @Bucks Did you configure build path? If not then add jar file in lib add configure build path(check module .xml in correct package).

Comment: @Bucks did you add newly edited changes in jar file and configure build path? If everything you did is correct then  restart eclipse. Or close all running projects that u run today.

Comment: @Parvathy Ok Leave that example,i created a new project in this project i need to include a xstream jar[need to do xml serlization/deserlization] What i did is i downloaded Stable Version: 1.4.4 Source distribution now tell me where should i add gwt.xml file and what are the lines i need to add

Comment: @Bucks if your package name is x.y.z; and all files in z you want. then add .gwt.xml file in package y it must have the following <module>
 <source path="z">
 </source>
</module>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23541/discussion-between-bucks-and-parvathy)

Comment: @Parvathy thnks i did its works now i know how to insert external jars in my gwt

Comment: @Parvathy Now my problem is How to load xstream and oracle db-connector jars

Comment: What is the right way to add a library? Create a lib folder and put the .jars inside or put the .jar inside  war/WEB-INF/lib?