# How to add another gwt project to classpath with maven?

Tags: gwt, maven, build

I have a gwt project (parent) that reference another gwt project (child), but when I build the parent project, I meeting this error:

> [ERROR] Unable to find
>   'com/company/package/conf.gwt.xml' on
>   your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a
>   classpath entry for source?

Could anyone tell me how to add child project to the classpath of the parent project with maven?

Comment: Where's the `conf.gwt.xml`? (`src/main/java` or `src/main/resources`?) How are you referencing the other project? (reactor build, or dependency already deployed/installed in a Maven repo?) Which Maven goal are you using? (before or after/equal-to `package`?)

Comment: conf.gwt.xml is in the child project.

Comment: parent project has below entry in gwt.xml: <inherits name="com.company.package.conf"/>

Comment: I use maven run the parent project: mvn gwt:run

Comment: Did you check `conf.gwt.xml` (and the *.java files BTW) is actually in the JAR for the _child_ project?

Comment: I am using the child project itself instead of JAR, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Select build path->configure build path->Projects-> Add->(select  project that you wanted to add)
click order and export and select the project

inherit the above module in .gwt.xml file

Eg: `<inherits name='com.mycompany.ProjectName'/>`(if you have ProjectName.gwt.xml in package com.mycompany then inherit like this)

for adding external jar refer the following link:

[Adding external jar in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515459/adding-external-jar-in-gwt/14515943#14515943)

Answer (score 0):

Parent project usually is just a shell.

You should ideally go for Parent, Child 1 and Child 2. Child 1 will have conf.gwt.xml module and Child 2 should use Child 1 and build/deploy gwt module with entrypoint to a war!!!

```
Maven Parent Project A

 --> Maven Child Project B1 ( gwt-module common.gwt.xml )

 --> Maven Child Project B2 ( gwt-module b2.gwt.xml ) -> dependency on B1 and inherits common.gwt.xml

 --> Maven Child Project B3 ( gwt-module b3.gwt.xml )

 --> Maven Child Project B4 ( gwt-module app.gwt.xml ) -> dependency on B1, B2, B3 and inherits common.gwt.xml, b3.gwt.xml and b3.gwt.xml and has entrypoint tag in its app.gwt.xml file
```

You question more towards maven project organization. You can find all about maven submodules - http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/

Comment: I am new to gwt, could you please explain it in more details?